# inserting variable inside if of list filter [ ]

Tags: python

The following code does not work

```
s = [x for x in s if s.count(x) > k]
```

where `s` is my list and `k` is some natural number but if I put `4` in place of `k` it works. Is it possible to work out variable `k` there?

Comment: what is k supposed to be?

Comment: It is supposed to work with variables. Show us more code - what is in `k` exactly?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `k` is some variable containing some natural number. Let's say it wrote `k=4` on previous code.

Comment: Then it should work.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha, then your code works just not very efficiently, if it does not work then k is not what you think it is

Comment: @SantoshLinkha: Perhaps `k` is a *string*, not an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work but it is pretty inefficient, doing a .count each time gives you quadratic complexity, creating a Counter dict and doing lookups will give you a linear solution:

```
from collections import Counter

cn = Counter(s)
print([x for x in s if cn[x] > k])
```